# Incorrect value returns

Tags: javascript

I use this function:

```
function search (){
  v = [[2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0]]
  if(v.indexOf(2.0) != -1){
    Logger.log ('if')
  }else{
    Logger.log('else')
  }
}
```

**editing**

My real need is in the values of words like this
I was answered about numbers so I did not change and only added

```
function search (){
  v = [["One"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"]]
  if(v.indexOf("One") != -1){
    Logger.log ('if')
  }else{
    Logger.log('else')
  }
}
```

And instead of "if" returning to me, "else" returns to me.
I apologize for the broken English

Comment: Looks like maybe you meant `v.findIndex(array => array.includes(2.0))` or maybe `v.findIndex(([number]) => number === 2.0)`

Comment: Check my updated answer. I've added the words instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You input array is a `multi`/`two` dimensional array. You are searching for `2.0` which is actually embedded inside another smaller array. Try changing the function to below.

```js
function search() {
  v = [
    ["One"],
    ["two"],
    ["three"],
    ["four"]
  ]
  if (v.findIndex(e => e[0] === 'One') != -1) {
    console.log('if')
  } else {
    console.log('else')
  }
}

search();
```

Comment: this would not work, as `indexOf` compares array _values_ with provided value `[2.0]`.
Provided `[2.0]` value is a new array whose _value_ woud be a different pointer to a different instance of `[2.0]`

Comment: It did not work for me
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays, so trying to use `indexOf` on the array of arrays will not work for your case. One option is to use `flat` and `some` in conjunction to flatten the array of arrays to one array and then check if the value is found inside the flattened array:

```js
function search (){
  v = [[2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0]];
  if(v.flat().some((a) => a === 2.0)){
    console.log('if');
  }else{
    console.log('else');
  }
}

search();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to write
`v = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];`?

Because that will print out `'if'`.
Reason is that in your example, each element of `v` array is an array of it's own.

If you really want it to be an array of arrays, then to make it work you can do this in the `if` statement:

`if ( v.flat().includes(2.0) )`

1. `flat` converts it from an array of array that contain a number, to an array of numbers.
2. `includes` is a nicer method to check if the array contains a value - no need to check for index :)

Answer (score 0):

array.indexOf() is not applicable for nested array. If your array is primitive types then it's working, but if array is non-primitive types then through indexOf you can't match the value.

Use this instated of your function:

```
v.findIndex(ele => [...new Set(ele)][0] == 2.0) >=0  ? 'if' : 'else'
```

[image]